Determining the number of cyclic groups of order $15$ in $\Bbb Z_{90}\oplus \Bbb Z_{36}$ and a generator for each subgroup.
I want to determine the number of cyclic subgroups of order $15$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{90}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{36}$ and also identify each of these subgroups using a generator.
I have first attempted to determine the number of elements of order $15$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{90}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{36}$. Here, for an element $(a,b) \in  \mathbb{Z}_{90}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{36}$,
$$15 = |(a,b)| = lcm(|a|, |b|)$$
Possible cases are:

Case 1: $|a| = 15, |b| = {1,3}$, we have $8\times 3 = 24$ elements
Case 2: $|a| = 5, |b| = 3$, we have $4\times 2 = 8$ elements

So, we have total of $32$ elements of order $15$. And, following from here $\frac{24+8}{\phi(15)} = \frac{32}{8} = 4$ subgroups.
Hoping that my reasoning and calculations until here is correct, I am facing issues with identifying these $4$ cyclic subgroups in terms of its generators.
My guess for generators:

For ($|a| = 15, |b| = 1$) is $\langle(6,0)\rangle$,
For ($|a| = 15, |b| = 3$) is $\langle(6,12)\rangle$ and $\langle(6,24)\rangle$,
For ($|a| = 5, |b| = 3$) is $\langle(18,12)\rangle$.

Are these generators correct? Also, if there are 4 subgroups of order 15, then shouldn't each one of them have 14 non-identity elements each?

Your calculations and (examples of) generators are correct, and your subgroups have indeed 14 non-zero elements.
